# Don't simplify integer square roots

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

How can I rewrite an expression like $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$ as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}$?

This works in principle, but gets immediately simplified back to the original expression

```
1/(2 Sqrt[
  3]) /. {Times[Rational[a_, b_], Power[c_, Rational[x_, y_]]] /; 
    x < 0 :> a Power[b^2 c, Rational[x, y]]}
```

Comment: I think this was talked about before in this forum. I do not think you can (without using Hold and related). Because this is one of those things Mathematica does automatically. i.e. automatic simplification.   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PshBS.png)

Comment: @Nasser good point, I'll look into another option then

Comment: You can also inactivate the `Power`, e.g. `1/(2 Sqrt[3])/.{c_^Rational[x_,y_] Rational[a_,b_]/;x<0:>a Inactive[Power][b^2 c,Rational[x,y]]}` returns `12^(-(1/2))`.