# Combining numbers with fractional powers together

Tags: simplifying-expressions, number-representation

I get lots of numerical answers that have integers raised to fractional powers multiplying each other.

A simple example:

2^(1/3) 3^(2/3)

which is of course 18^(1/3).

How do I get Mathematica to do combining of the factors "automatically"? i.e. give me the cube root of 18.

This seems like something obvious but I have tried all manner of Simplify, Collect, Factor etc etc but I cannot get the result I want.

Maybe I am having the proverbial very slow day mentally - but nothing seems to work.

Comment: [Related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/276940/72682)

Comment: @flinty That doesn't seem particularly relevant. The person is concerned about a root being simplified after the fact - I am looking at combining fractional powers to a single power as a simplified form.

Comment: it's relevant. It's related to the problem you're facing - Mathematica auto-simplifies. Try typing 18^(1/3). I get that this is working backwards, but suppose you could get 2^(1/3) 3^(2/3) into the form 18^(1/3). Mathematica would still auto-simplify it back to the two powers.

Comment: @flinty Yeah - I want to prevent the auto-simplify. As I said in the original question - I want the, from a human standpoint, the simplified 18^(1/3) form - not the Mathematica idea of simplification. Obviously my example was a simplistic one - I often have products with many terms where seeing the simplification would be a useful thing.